# Pointwise congergent subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis

Let {$f_n$} be a sequence of continuous functions on $\mathbb R$ which is pointwise bounded.

Does there exist subsequence {${f_n}_i$} such that

{${f_n}_i(x)$} converges for all $x\in \mathbb R$?

My attempt:

By Cantor diagonal argument I got subsequence coverging pointwise on rational numbers but I dont know how to proceed further. So now I suspect that there is some counter example. Any help is welcome!!!

Comment: What's pointwise bounded? Do you mean that $f_n$ is bounded for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: I don't quit understand the question. But this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem sounds related.

Comment: @Yanko When we say a sequence of functions is pointwise bounded, this means that $\{ f_n(x) \}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is a bounded sequence for each $x$ in the domain.

Comment: @Yanko "Pointwise bounded" is fairly standard terminology: It means that $(f_n(x))$ is bounded for every $x$.

Comment: It seems to me there must be a counterexample. No idea how to show that yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found a counterexample. Let $f_n(x)= \sin(nx)$ for $x \in [0,\pi]$ and $f_n(x) = 0$ otherwise. This sequence is continuous and uniformly bounded but it does not converge pointwise along any subsequence.

Indeed, note that if $n \neq m$, we have $$\int^\pi_{0} (f_n(x) - f_m(x))^2 dx = \int^\pi_0 [\sin^2(nx) - 2\sin(nx)\sin(mx) +\sin^2(mx) ]dx.$$
The middle term goes to zero by orthogonality and : $$\int^\pi_0 \sin^2(nx) dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$$ for any integer $n$. Thus $$\int^\pi_{0} (f_n(x) - f_m(x))^2 dx = \pi.$$ If $\{f_{n_i}\}$ converged at all points, then $$(f_{n_{i+1}} - f_{n_i})^2 \to 0$$ and then by the dominated convergence theorem we would have $$\int^\pi_0 (f_{n_{i+1}}( x) - f_{n_i}( x) )^2 dx \to 0$$ which is impossible.